# Using Gson to create arrays of objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I'd like to transform this JSON string into arrays of objects that I can manipulate in Java.

```
String jsonExample = "" +
            "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;03/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:23},{&#34;v&#34;:112}]},"+
            "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;04/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:14},{&#34;v&#34;:232}]},"+
            "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;05/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:18},{&#34;v&#34;:145}]},"+
            "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;06/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:22},{&#34;v&#34;:211}]},"+
            "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;07/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:18},{&#34;v&#34;:198}]},"+
            "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;08/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:15},{&#34;v&#34;:215}]}";
```

First, I unescape it:

```
String unescape = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(jsonExample2);
```

Then, I try to use Gson,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ViewsHistoric viewHistoric = gson.fromJson(unescape, ViewsHistoric.class);
```

with the following classes:

```
    public static class ViewsHistoric {
    private List<Row> r;
    public List<Row> getR() {return r;}
    public ViewsHistoric() {}
}

public static class Row {
    private Triplet c;
    public Triplet getC() {return c;}
    public Row() {}
}

public static class Triplet {
    private String v;

    public String getV() {return v; }
    public Triplet() {}
}
```

But I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2

Well, actually I've tried many other combinations of classes with Gson withing the last few hours, but with no luck.

Could anyone tell me how to transform that json string into java objects?

Comment: That doesn't seem like valid JSON. Start by looking over the [JSON format](http://json.org/). Note that a JSON _OBJECT_ maps to a Java object, a JSON _ARRAY_ maps to a Java array (or `Collection` type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your JSON was in an invalid format (even after unescaping).
2. Your `Triplet` class is an object, not a JSON array.

I've made a few modifications to your code, in order to make it work. Here you have a working example

```
public class Q24000071 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
             //the 'r' attribute, corresponding to 'ViewsHistoric' class, was missing
        String jsonExample = "{\"r\": ["
                + "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;03/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:23},{&#34;v&#34;:112}]},"
                + "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;04/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:14},{&#34;v&#34;:232}]},"
                + "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;05/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:18},{&#34;v&#34;:145}]},"
                + "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;06/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:22},{&#34;v&#34;:211}]},"
                + "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;07/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:18},{&#34;v&#34;:198}]},"
                + "{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;08/10/2013&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:15},{&#34;v&#34;:215}]}"
                + "]}";

        String unescape = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(jsonExample);
        System.out.println(unescape);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        ViewsHistoric viewHistoric = gson.fromJson(unescape,
                ViewsHistoric.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(viewHistoric));
    }

    public static class ViewsHistoric {

        private List<Row> r;

        public List<Row> getR() {
            return r;
        }

        public ViewsHistoric() {
        }
    }

    public static class Row {

        // Triplet is an array in the original JSON
            // of three elements, but an array.
        private Triplet[] c;

        public Triplet[] getC() {
            return c;
        }

        public Row() {
        }
    }

    public static class Triplet {

        private String v;

        public String getV() {
            return v;
        }

        public Triplet() {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try with below sample code after making small change in your actual JSON string that was not valid. Check it here [JSONLint - The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) for JSON string validation.

Here the resultant output is `Map<String, List<Row>>` where there is only one key `r` and the value is list of `Row` objects.

---

Sample code:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Row>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, List<Row>> data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, type);

System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

POJO classes:

```
class Row {
    private List<Triplet> c;
    // getter & setter
}

class Triplet {
    private String v;
    // getter & setter
}
```

output in pretty format:

```
{
  "r": [
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "03/10/2013"
        },
        {
          "v": "23"
        },
        {
          "v": "112"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "04/10/2013"
        },
        {
          "v": "14"
        },
        {
          "v": "232"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "05/10/2013"
        },
        {
          "v": "18"
        },
        {
          "v": "145"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "06/10/2013"
        },
        {
          "v": "22"
        },
        {
          "v": "211"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "07/10/2013"
        },
        {
          "v": "18"
        },
        {
          "v": "198"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "08/10/2013"
        },
        {
          "v": "15"
        },
        {
          "v": "215"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```